# Como incluir arquivo js no projeto html?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

No meu projeto, estou tentando incluir um arquivo .js, porém está apresentando o erro `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` toda vez que incluo o arquivo da seguinte maneira `<script type="text/javascript" src="dashboard/dist/js/main.js"></script>`. Acontece que esse problema apenas existe quando estou chamando minha biblioteca main dessa forma.

```html
<?php require "lib/Url.class.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'/>
        <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'/>
        <title>Dashboard - Marketing</title>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'/>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css'/>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="dashboard/dist/js/main.js"></script>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons' rel='stylesheet'/>
        
    </head>
    <nav class="nav-extended #0d47a1 blue darken-4">
        <div class="nav-wrapper container">
            <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
            <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a class="nav-link text-white" href="<?php echo URL::getBase(); ?>main">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link text-white" href="<?php echo URL::getBase(); ?>dados">Dados</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link text-white" href="<?php echo URL::getBase(); ?>precos">Preços</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
        <li><a class="" href="<?php echo URL::getBase(); ?>main">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="" href="<?php echo URL::getBase(); ?>dados">Dados</a></li>
        <li><a class="" href="<?php echo URL::getBase(); ?>precos">Preços</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Cara o problema aí ao que parece é o arquivo **main.js**, ele está ocasionando o problema e não a chamada dele. Basta vc abrir o console do navegador e ver a mensagem de erro. Lá mostra o arquivo e a linha do arquivo que estão com problemas.

Comment: @LeAndrade eu fiz isso e meu arquivo main.js está em branco. O erro que o console mostra está descrito acima. É como se tivesse um '<' inserido de forma errada.